# Change the pointer of the array into a much bigger array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

So I'm trying to experiment on Artificial Neural Network or at least scratching the surface. But here's my problem, I can't find a way to increase the array size that contains the pointers of other "neurons".

Here's my code for extending the size of my artificial neuron.

```
void extendNeuron(NeuronPtr *base, NeuronPtr * dest) { 
  (*(*base)->axon[sizeof((*base)->axon) / sizeof(*(*base)->axon) - 1]) = *dest;

  struct Neuron *** newAxon[sizeof((*base)->axon) / sizeof(*(*base)->axon) + 1];

  memcpy(newAxon, (*base)->axon, sizeof((*base)->axon));

  **(*base)->axon = ***newAxon;
}
```

And here's the struct for my Neurons

```
struct Neuron{
  char label[100]; 
  struct Neuron **axon[1];
};
```

Now my idea is to create another array of pointers (struct Neuron **axon) that is bigger than the current array (increase it by 1) and then change the pointer of the axon to that array. But I don't know how to do it.

So far here's my code:

```
  struct Neuron ** newAxon[sizeof((*base)->axon) / sizeof(*(*base)->axon) + 1]; //newAxon is supposed to be bigger than the axon of base 

  memcpy(newAxon, (*base)->axon, sizeof((*base)->axon)); //then I'm trying to copy the axon of base to the newAxon

  **(*base)->axon = ***newAxon; //then change the pointer of axon to newAxon
```

Comment: Any reason why you can't use a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) which can grow automatically?

Comment: What do you intend the `[1]` to mean in your code `struct Neuron **axon[1];` I know what it DOES mean and I really doubt that is what you intend.

Comment: Your use of `sizeof` also does not mean what you wanted it to mean (I know what you wanted as well as what it means and they are not the same).

Comment: An expert C++ programmer will recognize and correctly code situations in which managing your own raw storage is better than using `std::vector`.  But if you can't come close to doing that correctly, we can also assume you can't come close to knowing when it should be done.  NathanOliver understated his comment.  You SHOULD use std::vector, because even if there were a reason not to, you aren't ready to not use std::vector.

Comment: Use flexible array members, not the pre-C99 struct hack! And choose **one** language. **C is not C++ is not C!**

Comment: C has functions to make code more readable. Your code is hard to read - to say it politely.

Comment: @Olaf (or Jeremy) don't use the C++ tag on a question when you want to use advanced C approaches that are pointless in C++ (I can't tell whether Jeremy was wrong including the C++ tag or Olaf wrong assuming this is a C question not C++)

Comment: In C, by using `realloc()`, assuming you used `malloc()` or `calloc()` in the first place?

Comment: @JSF: Tell that OP! I did not add the tags!

Comment: That code has more stars in it than the Hollywood Walk of Fame.

Comment: I really have no idea what to put in that 3 line of code haha I'm sorry

Comment: Nathan, how does std::vector works?

JSF: Well I intend for it to start with one axon only, so when I put something it that first axon I'll increase it by one, and so on.

Comment: imitially use malloc() to allocate the array, then expand its' size using realloc()

Comment: `(*(*base)->axon[sizeof((*base)->axon) / sizeof(*(*base)->axon) - 1]) = *dest;`  - I strongly suggest adopting some more readable code style

Comment: Can you explain `struct Neuron **axon[1];` ? This is an array of pointers to pointers  . Why do you do this instead of using an array of pointers to struct Neuron?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume the following:

- `axon` will **always** created through `malloc` (or one of its derivative)
- `void extendNeuron(NeuronPtr *base, NeuronPtr * dest)` adds dest at the end of the array `base->axon`
- `axon` array if terminated with a null pointer - because in C you cannot extract the size of an array, so you must either keep its length in an auxiliary variable or use a convention to identifiy last element (or both like `argv`)
- `axon` is just an array of pointers to Neuron (`Neuron **`) instead of a `Neuron**[1]`

You would initialize a new `Neuron` that way:

```
void init(Neuron *neuron, const char *label) {
    strncpy(neuron->label, label, sizeof(neuron->label));
    neuron->label[sizeof(neuron->label)-1] = '\0'; /* if label was too long */
    neuron->axon = malloc(sizeof(Neuron *));
    /* control neuron->axon != NULL */
    neuron->axon[0] = NULL;
}
```

You need an auxiliary function to find the length of `axon` array:

```
int axon_length(Neuron *neuron) {
    int i = 0;
    while(neuron->axon[i] != NULL) i++;
    return i;
}
```

You can then extend a Neuron that way:

```
void extendNeuron(NeuronPtr *base, NeuronPtr * dest) {
    int len = axon_length(base);
    Neuron **p = realloc(base->axon, sizeof(Neuron *) * (n+2));
    /* test p != NULL ... */
    base->axon = p;
    p[n] = dest;
    p[n+1] = 0;
}
```

And do not forget to call `free(neuron->axon)` before releasing a `Neuron` to avoid memory leaks...